# Need to create photo slider using photo library photos in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, photo, alassetslibrary

I want photo slider like whts app has. It should access all the pics or some of the pics from in build photo library and it should be scrollable using scroll view.

I have tried with different photo viewer but everything has memory issue. So not sure if anyone has it's working solution. Really appreciate your help.

Thank you,

Ankita

Comment: Same problem here, too. And have to restrict the image to some number say 15 if more images are required have use the delegate of scrollview to load more and remove the image from it using the index property set on creation of image view

Comment: @AalokParikh: So is it working perfectly? If yes, can you please share your code?

Comment: Yes working perfectly, almost. But, can't share it now as I'm on my windows pc at home and no code is available to me at present. And also to share it I have to ask my project Manager, too. :(

Comment: But will try to help you out by providing the code as soon as possible

Comment: Not need to do restrict the number of images. You can go by reusable view approach. At at time max three view and images will be appear not more than this.

Answer (score 1):

This is working almost fine, but one small problem with backbord direction scrolling. Just try this out may be you can find some direction to go and may be find better solution using it.

(Have used ELCImagePicker to show first time all images and then on selecting one present the scrollview to show large images at a time 10 images are shown also have tweak the delegate method of ELCImagePickerController to get the index of selected image)

At first load ie when select image from ELCImagePickerController

```
- (void)elcImagePickerController:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info selectedIndex:(NSInteger)_index {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    for (UIView *v in [scrollview subviews]) {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }
    infoItems = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:info];
    CGRect workingFrame = scrollview.frame;
    workingFrame.origin.x = 0;
    int indexFrame = picker.selectedIndex;
    newIndex = indexFrame;
    for(int i = 0; i < [info count]; i++) 
    {
        NSDictionary *dict = [info objectAtIndex:i];
        UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];
        [imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        imageview.frame = workingFrame;
        imageview.tag = i;
        if(i >= indexFrame && i <= indexFrame + 9)
        {
            [scrollview addSubview:imageview];
            workingFrame.origin.x = workingFrame.origin.x + workingFrame.size.width;
        }
    }
    [scrollview setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(workingFrame.origin.x, workingFrame.size.height)];
    [scrollview scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, workingFrame.size.width, workingFrame.size.height) animated:NO];
    self.scrollview.hidden = NO;
    self.pageControll.hidden = NO;
    self.pageControll.numberOfPages = [[scrollview subviews]count];
    index = 0;
    lastContentOffset = scrollview.contentOffset.x;
    NSLog(@"lastContentOffset %.2f",lastContentOffset);
}
```

After that on scrollViews delegate method

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"ScrollViewDidEndDecelerating is called with subview(s) %d",[[scrollview subviews]count]); 
    if(lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.x)
    {

        index += (int)(scrollview.contentOffset.x - lastContentOffset)/scrollview.frame.size.width;
        newIndex += (int)(scrollview.contentOffset.x - lastContentOffset)/scrollview.frame.size.width;
        self.pageControll.currentPage = index;
        NSLog(@"Index incremented %d \n newIndex %d",index,newIndex);
        if(index == [[scrollView subviews]count]-1)
        {
            if(newIndex < [infoItems count]-1)
            {
                [self performSelector:@selector(reloadScrollViewWithNewImages)];
            }
        }
        [Appirater userDidSignificantEvent:YES];
    }
    else if(lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.x)
    {
        index -= (int)(lastContentOffset - scrollview.contentOffset.x)/scrollview.frame.size.width;
        newIndex -= (int)(int)(lastContentOffset - scrollview.contentOffset.x)/scrollview.frame.size.width;
        self.pageControll.currentPage = index;
        NSLog(@"Index decremented %d \n newIndex %d",index,newIndex);
        if(index == 0)
        {
            if(newIndex > 0)
            {
                newIndex -= 9;
                if(newIndex < 0)
                    newIndex = 0;
                [self performSelector:@selector(reloadScrollViewWithNewImages)];
            }
        }
        [Appirater userDidSignificantEvent:YES];
    }
    lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    NSLog(@"New lastContentOffset %.2f",lastContentOffset);
}
```

and the method used for reload the scrollView is as follow

```
-(void)reloadScrollViewWithNewImages
{
    for (UIView *v in [scrollview subviews]) {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }
    CGRect workingFrame = scrollview.frame;
    workingFrame.origin.x = 0;
    NSLog(@"reloadScrollView newIndex %d",newIndex);
    int indexFrame = newIndex;
    for(int i = 0; i < [infoItems count]; i++) 
    {
        NSDictionary *dict = [infoItems objectAtIndex:i];
        UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];
        [imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        imageview.frame = workingFrame;
        imageview.tag = i;
        if(i >= indexFrame && i <= indexFrame + 9)
        {
            [scrollview addSubview:imageview];
            workingFrame.origin.x = workingFrame.origin.x + workingFrame.size.width;
        }
    }
    [scrollview setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(workingFrame.origin.x, workingFrame.size.height)];
    [scrollview scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, workingFrame.size.width, workingFrame.size.height) animated:NO];
    self.scrollview.hidden = NO;
    self.pageControll.hidden = NO;
    index = 0;
    self.pageControll.numberOfPages = [[scrollview subviews]count];
    NSLog(@"number %d",[[scrollview subviews]count]);
    lastContentOffset = scrollview.contentOffset.x;
    NSLog(@"reloadScrollView's lastContentOffset %.2f",lastContentOffset);
}
```

and all used properties and private ivars declared in .h file's interface part required in this code are

Private ivars

```
NSInteger index;
float lastContentOffset;
```

Properties

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollview;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *infoItems;
@property (assign, atomic) int newIndex;
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CATiledLayer to draw image. CATiledLayer can be used to increase the performance of paging, panning, and zooming with high-resolution images or large sets of photos.

As i commented above you can go by reusable view approach means at a time only three imagview or view will be in memory. Let say you are showing photo number:2 so, you should have to keep photo:1,2 and3 in memory(i.e. to avoid flicker) no need to load all photos at a time. Suppose you are scrolling to photo number:3 then your logic should discard photo number:1 and should load photo number:2,3,4. If you are still not getting or don't know how to do this programmatically then don't worry. Apple's good sample code is available that is doing all you want.

[Sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010080-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

In above sample code they have displayed two way of displaying image. 
One is directly showing/setting the image into image view. 
Second is with drawing image with TileView using this method:
 `- (void)displayTiledImageNamed:(NSString *)imageName size:(CGSize)imageSize`

If you are thinking lot of about memory then definitely you have to use second approach.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Because UIImage memory doesn't get released. Can you please share source code if you have one?

Comment: Might be you are doing something wrong. check my edit. And add your images into that sample code. and check is it working or not? Directly don't add it on your code otherwise you didn't get idea whether the problem is due to your code or in sample code. By the way what is the size of your individual image?