# application crashes due to uiimageview

Tags: iphone

i have application in which i display around 50 images and when i reach to 30th image my application crashes due to memory issues. I have tried all the methods which i know but still problem is not solved. so please help me.

```
NSLog(@"%d",nn);
nn ++;
NSLog(@"%d",nn);
NSMutableArray* arr2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
arr2 = [Database executeQuery:@"select * from cartoon"];
if (nn == [arr2 count]) 
{
    nn = 0;
}
NSMutableDictionary*  dict1 = [arr2 objectAtIndex:nn];
NSLog(@"%@",dict1);              
NSString * both_name = [NSString string];
both_name = [both_name stringByAppendingString:[dict1 objectForKey:@"mainpk"]];
both_name = [both_name stringByAppendingFormat:@".  "];
both_name = [both_name stringByAppendingString:[dict1 objectForKey:@"name"]];
NSLog(@"both %@",both_name);
label1.text = both_name;
imgv.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",[dict1 objectForKey:@"name"]]];  `
```

Comment: What does this code have to do with the problem?  What kind of help are you looking for other than the obvious (i.e.: if 30 images don't fit in memory, don't load 30 images)?

Comment: Check my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758454/need-to-create-photo-slider-using-photo-library-photos-in-iphone/11760226#11760226 might be it will help you.

Comment: Check my answer:[http://stackoverflow.com/a/11791089/1132951](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11791089/1132951) this might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load 50 images into the memory and not expect to have troubles? 
How large are they file size-wise?

It is better to just load the image when it is needed / shown. Try splitting the actual image from the info of the image (name, size, whatever else) and load those into your system, maybe show some placeholders instead.
Then when you show a particular image then load the actual image into your memory and show it.

Answer (score 0):

The code **[dict1 objectForKey:@"mainpk"]** is  not returning a string.

**Errors in Your Code:**

In the below line you are creating the Dictionary with No keys.

```
NSMutableDictionary*  dict1 = [arr2 objectAtIndex:nn];
```

Then accessing the string through invalid key.

```
[dict1 objectForKey:@"mainpk"]];
```

Appending the invalid value to the string

```
[both_name stringByAppendingString:[dict1 objectForKey:@"mainpk"]];
```

This will crash :)

**This will work:**

```
NSMutableDictionary*  dict1 =  [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc ] initWithCapacity: 0];

[dict1 setObject: @"test" forKey: @"mainpk"];
[dict1 setObject: @"test1" forKey: @"name"];    

NSString * both_name = [NSString string];
both_name = [both_name stringByAppendingString:[dict1 objectForKey:@"mainpk"]];
both_name = [both_name stringByAppendingFormat:@".  "];
both_name = [both_name stringByAppendingString:[dict1 objectForKey:@"name"]];
NSLog(@"both %@",both_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't load that many pictures at once. There isn't enough memory.

1. Only load what you are showing
2. Don't make your images any bigger than you need(use small thumbnails if you need a preview of some sort)
3. Don't use imageNamed: , it caches the image and eats up ram. Use imageWithFile: instead.